# Zkteco Time Attendance Terminal (K14) (Auto download logs to DB)

Tags: time-and-attendance, zkteco

I'm using Zkteco k14 and the app that comes with it. The app comes with a feature that auto downloads Zkteco device logs to the DB. The bad thing is, it's only has 1 min. interval and it's kinda buggy.

My question is. Is there a way or a script to make downloading logs from device to my DB without manually downloading it using the app? Thanks!

Comment: https://youtu.be/7CXILnRWjLE This is a biometric cloud application, this supports, K14 with ADMS, Check if this helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way using the SDK provided by Zkteco, I been using it with my application. Check this link:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1104538/Csharp-ZKTeco-Biometric-Device-Getting-Started

Good luck!

Comment: is there an example to auto download logs to the database ?

Comment: you may download logs to your database using the SDK. If you want it auto, you can run your app as a scheduled job. Or you may use one of the device events.